# Change height of an SKShapeNode

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have an SKShapeNode which moves down when a sprite gets close to the top of the screen. However I can't seem to change the height of the frame.

Changing the property directly gives me the error 'Expression is not assignable'.

So I tried this code:

```
        //Move the world down
        world.position = CGPointMake(0.0f, -(20.0f));
        SKAction* moveDown = [SKAction moveToY:(world.position.y - 50.0f) duration:1];
        [world runAction:moveDown];
        CGRect temp = world.frame;
        temp.size.height = (world.frame.size.height / 1.2);
        world.frame = temp;
```

but it says I can't assign the frame as it's read-only.

Answer (score 3):

The frame of an SKShapeNode is read-only. If you would like to change the node's height, you can replace this

```
CGRect temp = world.frame;
temp.size.height = (world.frame.size.height / 1.2);
world.frame = temp;
```

with this

```
world.yScale = 1.0 / 1.2;
```

Comment: It says that world did not contain a property named size, so I tried it with frame.size but was left with the same error as before.

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: `1.0/1.2` is about `0.83`. That's a small change. Try testing with `world.yScale = 2.0;`

Comment: After trying the code, I realised that changing the yScale simply stretches the object rather than extending it. This causes an unwanted visible change as there are children in the SKShapeNode and they cannot get stretched.

Comment: I suggest you add x and y scaling factors to the `CGPath` that defines the `SKShapeNode`'s shape.

Comment: Isn't that going to make the node wider than the screen?

Comment: If you want to make your SKShapeNode larger/smaller without looking stretched, you will need to redefine the shape node.

Comment: And how do I do that?