# SpriteKit -- Change SKShapeNode Size

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, cgrect, skshapenode

I have a `SKShapeNode` created by `shapeNodeWithRect: cornerRadius:`. This rounded rect is a child of an SKEffectNode so I can set `shouldRasterize = YES`.

I'd like to change the width of this node based on the user's touch. i.e. As they move their finger horizontally to the right, the rect gets bigger (and smaller when they move it to the left).

1. I can do it by replacing the original `SKShapeNode` with a new one with the new size (but this is bad).
2. I've tried running a resize action on the `SKEffectNode` and the `SKShapeNode` (but this doesn't work because resize only works on `SKSpriteNotes` [[SKAction Apple Docs -- Resize]](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/resizeToWidth:duration:)):

`[self runAction:[SKAction resizeToWidth:newSize.width height:newSize.height duration:0]];
[self.shapeNode runAction:[SKAction resizeToWidth:newSize.width height:newSize.height duration:0]];`

3. I could change the xScale like in this answer: [Change height of an SKShapeNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977654/change-height-of-an-skshapenode). But if I do this, the `SKShapeNode` gets pixelated.

**How should I do this?**

It's so easy in UIKit (just set the frame of a UIView)...

Comment: Have you tried to scale?

Comment: @sangony -- I have tried to scale (see #3 in my question). The issue is that scaling the node from small to big makes it pixelated.

Comment: If pixelation is an issue then there's very little you can do about it. I recently posted an answer of resizing a SKLabelNode which dealt with very similar problems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354494/how-should-i-resize-label-nodes-in-spritekit/29354830#29354830

Comment: 1.  What is wrong with redrawing it each pass?  It might be intensive but if it works...
2.  If it pixelates when you stretch it, create the shape as the widest x you would need and immediately scale it down.   Then, as they touch the screen, increase the scale to approach 1.  Scaling down causes minimal quality loss.  Scaling up pixelates.  Just inverse your process.

Comment: @meisenman -- 1. The issue with recreating on each pass is animating the change. 2. Agree with this as possible solution (though it doesn't work very well with my specific implementation because I have lots of these SKShapeNodes on screen and am worried about scaling down that many objects).

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but why are you setting shouldRasterize? Much like any vector after rasterizing  scaling gets fuzzy. That is likely why it is pixelating. If it is needed then I don't see a work around other than crazy big and scale down or recreate as needed.  After you create it you could try self.shapeNode.texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest but not hopeful that will help much.

Answer (score 3):

Create your `SKShapeNode` objects with large sizes, then immediately scale them down. If you do this, you shouldn't run into blurry or pixelated nodes.

In Swift 4.0:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var roundedRect: SKShapeNode!
    didMove(to view: SKView) {
         roundedRect = SKShapeNode(rect: Constants.RoundedRect.largeInitialRect, cornerRadius: Constants.Rect.largeInitialCornerRadius)
         // configure roundedRect
         addChild(roundedRect)
         scaleRoundedRect
    }

    func scaleRoundedRect(to size: CGSize) {
        roundedRect.xScale = roundedRect.xScale / frame.width * size.width
        roundedRect.yScale = roundedRect.yScale / frame.height * size.height
    }
}
```

In Objective-C:

```
@implementation GameScene

    - (void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
        CGRect largeRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0); // replace with your own values
        CGFloat largeCornerRadius = (CGFloat) 0; // replace with your value
        _roundedRect = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithRect:largeRect cornerRadius:largeCornerRadius];
        CGSize initialSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0); // replace with your value
        [self scaleRoundedRectToSize:initialSize];
    }

    - (void) scaleRoundedRectToSize:(CGSize)size {
        _roundedRect.xScale = _roundedRect.xScale / _roundedRect.frame.size.width * size.width;
        _roundedRect.yScale = _roundedRect.yScale / _roundedRect.frame.size.height * size.height;
    }


@end
```